# Can we change more than 50 Pandas Dataframe to excel in one sheet and use Vlookup to view separate dataframes based on key value

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am looking basically for vlookup function in excel. Except that I want to create VLOOKUP functionality in Excel with the help of Python.

Take for example,

There is student information stored in dataframe like.

name: Raghav
age: 21
hobbies: singing
qualifications: B.tech.

name Ram
age:27
hobbies: dancing
qualifications: MBA

Now what I want is Worksheet will have only one cell, and If I select Raghav there, then it will only show Raghav information.

If Ram is selected there then it should show Ram information.

It is basically a vlookup function.

But I want to convert my 50 plus individual dataframes to excel with dropdown and only 1 dataframe viewable at a time.

```
pd.to_excel()

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

for x in Moving_Avg_Signal:
    # [tempDataframe.columns[1:14] ]
    tempDataframe = Moving_Avg_Signal[x][list(Moving_Avg_Signal[x].keys())[0]]
    underlyingValue = tempDataframe.iloc[0]["underlyingValue"]

    tempDataframe.drop(columns=['underlyingValue'],inplace=True)
    tempDataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=x, startrow=1, header=False)
    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets[x]
```

Right now, I have 50+ sheets in a single file. Hard to navigate.

Hope you understood my Query.

Comment: Is there anyone who can suggest something.